# Can I use a git SHA for the vsn field in an Erlang application?

Tags: erlang

What are the requirements for the `vsn` key in an Erlang application?

The [Erlang/OTP documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id73727) simply says:

> Version number, a string. Defaults to "".

Is there any required ordering between versions? If I use a git SHA, will I still be able to use relups or appups?

To rephrase:

**Is there anything in Erlang/OTP that requires a well-defined partial or total ordering in the `vsn` key?**

Answer (score 0):

The version can be any string, but with your idea I see 2 problems:

You will loose the ability to make comparison on version easily, I mean that you will need to maintain  a catalog of all existing versions just to know if one version is older than an other (it should be accessible via git)

but as far as git works at the project level, you cannot know the SHA, and as the app file is part of the project, you cannot fill the version before commiting unless the app file is out of the git repository, which is not really interesting.

Comment: We're using `rebar`, which means that the `foo.app` file doesn't need to be committed -- it's generated from `foo.app.src` at build-time, and rebar has hooks for using arbitrary scripts (and git) to generate it.

Comment: And the question was: "does anything in Erlang/OTP depend on a defined partial or total ordering in the Vsn value?"

Comment: Well if you want to use rebar deps option such as minimal version, it will fail.